# Select an element whose id matches href attribute jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select an element whose `id` matches the `href` of an `<a>` element

HTML

```
<a href="web"></a>
<a href="app"></a>

<div id="web"></div>
<div id="app"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $href = $(this).attr('href');
   var $id = $('div').attr('id');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   //HERE I WANT TO SELECT THE DIV WHOSE "id" MATCHES THE "href" of the <a> clicked 
   $('div').id($href).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a leading `#` to the `$href` to get the selector of the div like following.

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('#' + $href).addClass('active'); // this is what you need to do
});
```

Comment: That's it! The thing is, what $('#' + $href) does?

Comment: `$('#' + $href)` selects the div which id is same as the cliked `<a>`'s `href`.  @tavozapata

Comment: Oh I see, I'd never have imagined that the addition sign would do that